# JQuery script with different parameter on the same page

Tags: jquery

I need to use the same JQuery script with different parameters on the same page.
My script is:

```
/*
 * Simple Image Slider
 * Read more at: http://stuff.nekhbet.ro/2009/06/23/simple-image-gallery-navigation-slider-plugin-in-jquery.html
 * Version: 1.0.1
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Trimbitas Sorin-Iulian
 * Free of use (personal and commercial) as long as you keep this header in the file
 * Requires: jQuery v1.3+
*/
;(function($) {

    var totalCount = 0,selector,options,firstPos = 0,isRunning = false;

    $.fn.simple_slider = function(settings) {
        settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.simple_slider.defaults, settings);
        selector = this.selector;
        options = settings;
        //get the number of images
        totalCount = $(selector + " img").size();
        //init
        _init();

        function _init(){
            //hide them all (with the exception of the first X images)
            $(selector + " img").each(function(i){
                if (i >= options.display){
                    this.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
            //put actions (onclick) on the buttons for navigation
            //left
            $("#" + options.leftID).click(function (){
                if (isRunning == false){
                    _goLeft();
                }
            });
            $("#" + options.leftID).hover(function (){
                $(this).addClass("simple_slider_hover");
                }, function (){
                $(this).removeClass("simple_slider_hover");
            });
            //right
            $("#" + options.rightID).click(function (){ 
                if (isRunning == false){
                    _goRight();
                }
            });
            $("#" + options.rightID).hover(function (){
                $(this).addClass("simple_slider_hover");
                }, function (){
                $(this).removeClass("simple_slider_hover");
            });
            $("#" + options.leftID).addClass("simple_slider_disabled");
            _checkNavigation();
        }

        function _goLeft(){
            isRunning = true;
            if (firstPos > 0){
                //remove the last one
                $(selector + " img:eq("+ (firstPos + options.display - 1) + ")").fadeOut("slow", function (){
                    firstPos--;
                    //add one from the beginning
                    $(selector + " img:eq("+ (firstPos) +")").fadeIn("slow",function(){
                        isRunning = false;
                        _checkNavigation();
                    });
                });             
            } else {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

        function _goRight(){
            isRunning = true;
            if (firstPos + options.display < totalCount){
                //remove the first one
                $(selector + " img:eq("+ firstPos +")").fadeOut("slow", function (){
                    firstPos++;
                    //add one from the end
                    $(selector + " img:eq("+ (firstPos + options.display - 1) +")").fadeIn("slow",function(){
                        isRunning = false;
                        _checkNavigation();
                    });
                });             
            } else {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

        function _checkNavigation(){
            //left
            if (firstPos == 0){
                $("#" + options.leftID).addClass("simple_slider_disabled");
            } else {
                $("#" + options.leftID).removeClass("simple_slider_disabled");
            }
            //right
            if ( (firstPos + options.display) >= totalCount){
                $("#" + options.rightID).addClass("simple_slider_disabled");
            } else {
                $("#" + options.rightID).removeClass("simple_slider_disabled");
            }
        }

    }

    $.fn.simple_slider.defaults = {
        display             :   4,
        leftID              :   null,
        rightID             :   null
    };

})(jQuery);
```

On the page I try to use this, but work only last on page:

```
   <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#slide_interviu-special').show();
        $('#interviu-special_content').simple_slider({
            'leftID': 'leftNav',
            'rightID': 'rightNav',
            'display': 4
        });
        $('#slide_interviu-special_bottom').show();
        $('#interviu-special_bottom_content').simple_slider({
            'leftID': 'leftNav_bottom',
            'rightID': 'rightNav_bottom',
            'display': 8
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do all the elements such as `slide_interviu-special` etc. exist? Did you spell the IDs correctly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your question a bit so we can provide better assistance - "*but work only last on page*" - what exactly is the problem you're having? Is there a specific error message (if so include it)? Is the behavior simply not as expected (if so describe it)? It can also be helpful to reproduce the error at http://jsfiddle.net